# Replace Values in Nested XML Using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How to replace the values in nested xml using Powershell?

How do i replace the values of "Racers", "Pacers" "Losers" from "false" to "True" using PowerShell ?

````
<Tester>
<TesterSection>
 <section name="TestingApp" type="Amazon,Google" />
</TesterSection>
<application>
 <add key="Minimum" value="1" />
 <add key="Maximum" value="true" />
 <add key="Runners" value="N/A" />
 <add key="Racers" value="false" />
 <add key="Pacers" value="false" />
 <add key="Losers" value="false" />
</application>  
</Tester> ```
````

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: are you changing these three because of the `key` values or because their `value` values are all `false`; that is - what if `Runners` was also `false`, would its `value` have to change, too, or just these three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
# Simulate the XML in a string
$text = @"
<Tester>
<TesterSection>
 <section name="TestingApp" type="Amazon,Google" />
</TesterSection>
<application>
 <add key="Minimum" value="1" />
 <add key="Maximum" value="true" />
 <add key="Runners" value="N/A" />
 <add key="Racers" value="false" />
 <add key="Pacers" value="false" />
 <add key="Losers" value="false" />
</application>  
</Tester>
"@

$xml = [xml]$text
# You can load the file with
# $xml = [xml] "c:\temp\thefile.xml"

# List of keys to change
$tochange = "Racers","Pacers","Losers"

foreach ($add in $xml.Tester.application.add)
{
  # value before
  $add.value
  # modification
  if ($tochange -contains $add.key)
  {
    $add.value= "true"
  }
  # name after
  $add.value
}
# Or in a sigle line
#$xml.Tester.application.add | % {if ($_.value -eq "false"){$_.Value ="true"}}
$xml.Save("c:\temp\FileAfter.xml")
```

Comment: Can i not use something like this?

```$xml = [xml]$text

$xml.configuration.appSettings.add | % {if ($_.key -eq "Racers","Pacers","losers"){$_.Value ="true"}}```

Comment: Not `-eq` with a list but you can create a list ans use `-contains`.

Comment: ```-contains``` is not replacing the values :(

Comment: I edit my answer to show you the way I use `-contains`

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion is to use xpath. Here is a working snipper for your example

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<Tester>
    <TesterSection>
        <section name="TestingApp" type="Amazon,Google" />
    </TesterSection>
    <application>
        <add key="Minimum" value="1" />
        <add key="Maximum" value="true" />
        <add key="Runners" value="N/A" />
        <add key="Racers" value="false" />
        <add key="Pacers" value="false" />
        <add key="Losers" value="false" />
    </application>  
</Tester>
"@

foreach ($key in $("Racers","Pacers","Losers")) {
    $xml.selectNodes("//application/add[@key='$key']") | %{ $_.value = "true" }
}
$xml.Save("c:\temp\FileAfter.xml")
```

Comment: Now it works, I replace  `"` by  `'` and  `'` by  `"` in the XPath. It's a nice way.